# How does Kivy render its uix components like VideoPlayer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

using `kivy.uix.videoplayer`, we can see that it's actually made of several other widgets: VideoProgressBar, VideoVolume, ...

However, I can't find how are they placed together: there isn't any `kv` file in the repository, or any add_widgets on them, so I'm wondering how it works.

I am going to have to customize Videoplayer, and the documentation states that it's not customizable, so I'm wondering about redoing it for my purposes

Comment: When you say "there isn't any kv file in the repository", have you not found `style.kv` in `kivy/data`?

Comment: I did not see it included, I'm gonna look at it thanks. I searched with github search bar, and no kv results were returned